# how to count heterogeneous double letters from a list of vectors in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
df = read.table(text="ID    V1
1   'TT AA TC GG' 
2   'AT GG CC TG AA' 
3   'GT AC TT AT'
4   'GC TA CT'
5   'AC'
6   'AA TT CC GG'", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

The `V1` column has different length of strings with homo-or hetero- double letters separated by space. I would like to count the number of hetero- double letters for each row. 
I used `strsplit(as.character(df$V1), " ")` to convert lists. I know how to do it in a single string but not in lists. for example,  `A=c("AA","TT","CC","AC","TC")` to count `sum(substr(A,1,1) != substr(A,2,2))` the expected result:

```
df = read.table(text="ID    V1  num
1   'TT AA TC GG'   1
2   'AT GG CC TG AA'    2
3   'GT AC TT AT'   3
4   'GC TA CT'  3
5   'AC'    1
6   'AA TT CC GG'   0", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to split the strings and then use `substr` to extract the 1st and 2nd character separately, compare it to get a logical vector and `sum` it.

```
df1$num <- vapply(strsplit(df$V1, "\\s+"), function(x)
                        sum(substr(x,1,1)!= substr(x,2,2)), 0)
df1$num
#[1] 1 2 3 3 1 0
```

---

Or a compact option would be to count the words (`\\w+`) with `str_count` after removing all the homogenous substrings with `gsub`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(trimws(gsub("(\\S)\\1+", "", df$V1)), "\\w+")
#[1] 1 2 3 3 1 0
```

It should also work with leading/lagging spaces

```
str_count(gsub("(\\S)\\1+", "", df$V1), "\\w+")
#[1] 1 2 3 3 1 0
```

Comment: I am just curious what the difference `sapply` and `vapply` used here? You initially used `sapply` later you changed to `vapply`. I am struggling with `apply`s such as `lapply, mapply, tapply, sapply, vapply`

Comment: @user3354212  Initially I used `lapply` to test it.  The `lapply/sapply/vapply` can be applied to `list`.  Here the output of `strsplit` is a `list`.  The difference is that `lapply` returns a `list` output, while `sapply/vapply` returns a vector (which you really wanted as your intention is to create a column in the dataset).  Using `vapply`, it becomes faster as there is an additional check `0` so that it returns a numeric value.  In case, if there is any problem, it will fail.  The `mapply/Map` can be used with two lists. i.e. comparing corresponding elements of list. `tapply` is a group by

Comment: @user3354212  tapply is a group by operation which can either return a list/vector depending upon whether there is any difference in length of output in each group.  Even `sapply` can return a `list` when there is difference in length, but its default option is `simplify = TRUE` just like `mapply` and `Map` difference.